# Unexpected sequence in bash recursive loop

Tags: macos, bash

This is how I expect a bash loop to sequence the output:

```
for i in $(seq 2); do
    echo $i
    echo $(expr $i + 10)
done
1
11
2
12
```

This is how it sequences for a recursive folder file operation:

```
for file in "$(find . -name '*.txt')"; do
    echo "$file";
    newfile="${file//\.txt/.csv}"
    echo "$newfile";
    mv '$file' '$newfile'
done
./dir1/a.txt
./dir2/b.txt
./dir2/dir3/c.txt
./dir1/a.csv
./dir2/b.csv
./dir2/dir3/c.csv
mv: rename $file to $newfile: No such file or directory
```

I've tried the `mv` call with name variables wrapped in `"` and no quotes, which return different errors.

Grateful for a pointer where I'm going wrong.

Comment: This is [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and the linked (from there) [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) discusses more appropriate ways to read data line-by-line.

Answer (score 3):

There should not be quotes around the `$(find)` command: the quotes cause all of the file names to be concatenated into one large string. The quotes in the `mv` command should be double quotes: variables aren't expanded inside single quotes.

```
for file in $(find . -name '*.txt'); do
    echo "$file"
    newfile="${file//\.txt/.csv}"
    echo "$newfile"
    mv "$file" "$newfile"
done
```

This isn't the best way to loop through a list of files. It'll trip up on any file names with spaces. A better way is to pipe `find` to a `read` loop.

```
find . -name '*.txt' | while read file; do
    ...
done
```

This will handle most file names fine. It'll still have trouble with files with leading spaces, with backslashes, or with embedded newlines (which, technically, are legal). To handle those:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    ...
done
```

`-print0` and `-d $'\0'` take care of newlines. `IFS=` keeps read from dropping leading whitespace. `-r` tells it not to interpret backslashes specially.

For what it's worth, the `.` in `.txt` doesn't need to be escaped. `.` isn't a special character here. And `/%` would be better than `//` since the replacement should only be done at the end of the string.

```
newfile=${file/%.txt/.csv}
```

Comment: That's what I was looping for. Thanks John

Comment: Like this answer and that comment.